# Call a Web API in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api2

I have developed a Web Api in .net  and I would like to have some kind of service that would download emails from an outlook account and put data from emails in my database using my API (for example I would like to create a new Instance of my Class Player that is in my Api and then persist it on my database). I am very new to this so I apologize if anything is not clear in my question please don't mind asking me details.

I have managed to connect and extract data from emails already on another solution, it works but now I want to create something cleaner that would run all day long to check if there is new mails and then create new "Players" for example using my API

So my question is : is creating a Windows Service a good choice ? (I'm guessing creating a new project in the API's solution dedicated to this feature is a good choice).

I have read some articles about Self-Hosting WEB API on Windows Services but I'm not sure thats what I want to do

Any tips / advises would be more than welcome ! TY

Comment: Of course, on Windows a **Windows Service** is the right (and canonical) solution in writing **daemons**. I imagine your API wakes up at reguler intervals in order to check and process emails: in that scenario an alternative solution maybe writing a standalone non-interactive process, scheduled by the **Windows Task Scheduler**.

Comment: Alright Thanks I will look more into that, you should maybe put that as a potential answer to my question so I make it the answer ?